# Given $Re(f(z))$ and the fact that $f(z)$ is analytic, find $Im(f(z))$

Tags: complex-analysis, integration, complex-numbers

The question I'm trying to answer:

---

Find an analytic function $f(z)$ whose real part $u(x,y)$ is:

$$\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}$$

---

An analytic function satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann relations. So I thought to differentiate the real function, and then integrate it, to find two expressions for $v(x,y) = Im(f(z))$.  The partial integrals are:

$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{-2xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} $$

$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = \frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}  = - \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} $$

The next step would be to integrate and find $v(x,y)$.

Is this the right track?  Is it possible to integrate these expressions?  If so, where would you start?

Comment: Yes, keep going. Can you integrate $\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$ with respect to $y$ (keeping $x$ fixed)? What do you get?

Comment: That works, it's the standard way. Here, we can have a short-cut, because we know $1/z = \overline{z}/\lvert z\rvert^2 = \frac{x-iy}{x^2+y^2}$. So we see it's the real part of $\frac{i}{z}$.

Comment: Something to remember is that when you integrate a partial derivative you integration "constant" is a function of the other variable. So for instance if I have $\partial f / \partial x = x$ the integral is $f= x^2/2 + g(y)$

Comment: @DanielFischer I think it would have been better to just tell him that staring at it hard works here than to tell him a solution.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan: My integrals are a bit rusty, this is my first math class in many years.  I found the first integral with user1337's hint.  A hint for the second integral would be appreciated.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Would you have a hint on how to solve $\int{\frac{y^2-x^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}dx}$ ?  From your comment I can see that the answer must be $v(x,y) = \frac{x}{x^2 + y^2} + h(y) + C$.

Comment: Since you have a $(x^2+y^2)^2$ in the denominator, a natural ansatz would be $\frac{w(x,y)}{x^2+y^2}$ with a polynomial $w$. That yields $(x^2+y^2)\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}(x,y) - 2xw(x,y) = y^2-x^2$, and the solution $w(x,y) = x$ is not too hard to see.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Thanks.  So you just have to see that it's in the form $\frac{f'g - fg'}{g^2}$.  Might be a bit hard to spot during exam time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. In order to integrate $$\frac{-2xy}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$$ for example you could substitute $p(y)=x^2+y^2$.

Comment: Thanks!  So $dp = 2y dy$ and $v(x,y) = \frac{x}{x^2+y^2} + g(x) + C$.  Any hint for the other integral?

Comment: Note that $g(x)$ can "absorb" the constant C. Differentiate this $v(x,y)$ w.r.t. $x$ and compare with $-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$.